# Exercise 1.9 of K&R book

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve the exercise 1.9 of the K&R book , 2nd edition , well I'll write here the exercise and then explain what I think that I need to do and then, my code and my doubts.

**Exercise:**

Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank.

As far as I can understand, I need to make the program using what I learnt in the chapters before.

My view point is that I need to discover a way to say in the language of C that when appears more than one blank followed by another blank it will give me the phrase with only one blank. But how can I say to the computer that ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* ToDo - make a program where when the user input a phrase or
 * something that contains more than one blank followed by another
 * it will transform the input with only one blank */
int main()
{
    int c, b;
    b = ' ';        
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){ /*don't need explanation*/
        /*my doubts start here , how can i say more than one blank ?*/
        /* or how can i say if the getchar has  one blank followed by another ?*/

        if (c == +b) /* trying to say if the getchar has more than one blank but i think this is not correct*/
            c = b;   /*then it will turn in only one blank*/        
    }
    putchar(c);         
}
```

Comment: i was asking for help to it , since i have nobody to answer me that ^^ , anyways i can't even ask it here since i don't know how to write my code here ..

Comment: @Miguel Can you copy and paste your code to the Notepad? If you do, try doing so, and then copy and paste it from there.

Comment: Just this once, paste up the code, no matter how abysmal the formatting is, and one of us will edit it for you.

Comment: that's the problem it won't let me ... he recognizes that it is code and demands me to format it ...

Comment: You should re-read the previous chapters. If that does not help, you should read another C book. Not every book is suitable for every reader. And have a look at `ctype.h` to detect _whitespace_.

Comment: For the 5th (or so) time: Who do you mean by "it" or "he"? Is there someone sitting next to you, keeping you from ctrl-C/ctrl-V?

Comment: @Miguel Select the code and click the `{}` button on the top of the editor window.

Comment: @olaf yep i did it , im with this problem at some time and only now i tried to find help from anothers , for example at this book i didnt have learn the ctype.h , as i explained i'm trying to make the program with what i have learnt before

Comment: @Eugene Sh thank you , it finally helped ... there is the code

Comment: Where did you get this syntax from `+b` ?

Comment: `getchar` - as the name implies - gives **one single** character per call - think about this. Oh, and: C does not support _regular expressions_ natively.

Comment: `+b` is a curiousity. Do you mean this? It's essentially a no-op but will promote `b` to `int` if necessary.

Comment: @Bathsheba: as much as simply `b` would. To me it looks like `+` meaning "one or more" as in a regexpr.

Answer (score 3):

Print every character you come across including blanks, but when you come across a blank, do nothing until you come across a non-blank, then print that.  Repeat until EOF.

In ANSI C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    if (c == ' '){
      while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
    ;
      putchar(c);
    }
  }
}
```

Example input and output:

```
asd          asd            2
asd asd 2
Hello         I AM           space
Hello I AM space
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is this:

Pseudocode:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
   // c contains the character we've just read

   if (c is blank and the previous read char is blank)
   {
     // do nothing
     continue;
   }

   putchar(c);   // print that char

   copy c to previous char
}
```

Comment: I think this helped me a lot , it seems a really easy code to do , but i keep thinking if in your code i need to use more than what i learn in the book , i'll see ...thank you ^^

Comment: @Miguel I don't think you need more that you've read in the previous chapters of the book. My suggestion is really very very basic and simple. All you need are following operators `&&`, `==` and `=`.

Comment: Actually Cruentus_Nex  has posted the complete solution which is basically the same as my pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation of Jabberwocky's pseudocode. Please only read if you've tried to implement Jabberwocky's pseudocode on your own since it makes for a better learning experience:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, p;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        if (c == ' ' && p == ' ')
        {
            continue;
        }
        putchar(c);
        p = c; /* copy to c to p to track previous character */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but because I just solved that exercise I thought about sharing it here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
        int c, nspaces;

        nspaces = 0;
        c = getchar();

        while(c != EOF) {
                if (c == ' ') {
                        if (nspaces > 0) {
                                ++nspaces;
                        } else {
                                putchar(c);
                                ++nspaces;
                        }
                } else {
                        putchar(c);
                        nspaces = 0;
                }
                c = getchar();
        }

        return(0);
}
```

For my solution I just have a counter that keeps track on how many consecutive empty space characters are found. Only if nspaces is 0 then c is printed back to the terminal. Finding a non space char resets the nspaces back to 0. With this there is no need to keep track of the previous char or calling getchar() multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Correct me if I'm wrong but

"ex) Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank."

As I understand it, you gotta :
-Take the input

-Clear the input if more than one blank is there (could be a space, a '\t' or anything, man ascii)

-print the cleared string

-return

I will not explain how to take the input, just use main's argument.

Then you have to check for blanks.

Just increment a counter to the first blank occurrence and check if the next one is a blank or not. 
If it is, just keep incrementing, if it's not, copy the char to a new char*.

return that char * (don't make this whole thing in one function please).

print it.

return 0.

Comment: exactly , i'm doing my exercises like u say ... i try to explain myself what i need to do and then " transform it " in Programming language . thank you for the help man :)

Comment: Don't forget to use two strings, don't try to erase blanks from the first string. Just don't copy those blanks into the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char c = 0;
    char  prevchar = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if(c != ' ' || prevchar != ' ')
            putchar(c);
        prevchar = c;
    }
}
```

What this does:  Declares a second var to act as a sort single character buffer to check if the previous character was a space.  The if then ensures that putchar only fires if one them is not a space.  You can change the '\n' to EOF I use '\n' here so it only reads until the next return.

Comment: Thank you for the help , but as i wrote in the topic i want to use what i learnt before in the book , i didn't have learnt the int argc , char* argv[] already , anyways i will keep this code you have done for later :) .appreciated it

Comment: `c` as well as `prevchar` should be an `int`.

Comment: @Miguel In that case, replace `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` with `int main()` or `int main(void)`

Comment: it doesnt make difference ? and one thing , i didnt read about "char" only getchar and putchar , what's the difference ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, as I wrote the code I instinctively added that.  THe simple way to explain it is that the OS calls your program starting at main.  argc tells the OS the number of command line options there are and argv is an array of arrays to characters(in C++ terminology this would be an array of strings).  These are optional arguments you can pass to your program and parse to change program behavior when called.  An example would be the ls command in the Linux shell.  You can call ls without options or you can add one like ls -l.

Comment: I tried to " modify " the code , it wasnt really a change , but i don't know if it's your way to code or because im new , well i can't write here the code so was only to say that

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,nb=0;
    char sent[100];

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");

    for(i=0;(sent[i]=getchar())!='\n';i++)
    {
        if(sent[i]==' ')
        {
            nb++;
            if(nb>=2)
            {
                i--; 
                nb--;
            }
        }
        if(sent[i]!=' ')
        nb=0;
    }

    sent[i]='\0';

    printf("\nResult: ");

    for(i=0;sent[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        putchar(sent[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer of same question, I did this without using EOF. Especially for mobile users who can't use 'Ctrl+D'.